# Change navigation bartintcolor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, ios13

[image]The navigation barTintColor doesn't change when "prefers large titles" is selected. I tried changing it from Attribute Inspector and also programmatically. I can see the color change in storyboard but not while I run the app. I have the same problem with the titleColor as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `barTintColor`, you mean the color of the `navigationBar` itself, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to change the `backgroundColor` of the `navigationBar` for the *largeTitle* mode. It's completely different from the *normalMode*.

## With Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

or

## With Code

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .brown
```

## Result

[image: LargeTitle]

**Note that** the top white area is actually the `backgroundColor` of the `RootViewController` and you need to handle it manually.

<sub>try different colors for each one and play to more understand the behavior</sub>

Comment: The `backgroundColor` worked for me. And for the white part I added `view.backgroundColor = .red`.